# Select all tag assignments from latest 5 posts

Tags: php, mysql, tags, blogs, posts

I have three tables:

1. `post` (id) - has all the entries
2. `tag` (id) - has all the tags
3. `assign` (post_id,tag_id) - assigns tags to posts, may have multiple rows for a post

This is what I have so far:

> $sql_post = mysql_query("SELECT title,content,time,web FROM post ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 5");
>
> $sql_tag = mysql_query("SELECT tag.name,tag.id,post.id FROM assign LEFT JOIN tag ON assign.tag_id=tag.id LEFT JOIN post ON assign.post_id=post.id WHERE post.time>(SELECT MIN(time) FROM (SELECT time FROM post ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 6) two)");

I was thinking of putting it all into one big array, so something like this (sloppy summary):

```
array(
    post_id => array(
        "title" => "post's title...",
        "content" => "post's content...",
        "tag" => array(
            tag_id => "tag 1's name",
            tag_id => "tag 2's name
```

...and then using foreach's to display them on my blog.

Where I need help is the sql for `$sql_tag`. How do I make it so that it selects all of the assignments for the latest 5 posts? It only selects one tag for a post.

Answer (score 0):

Why not loop over the posts your interested in?

```
$sql_post = mysql_query("SELECT id, title,content,time,web FROM post ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 5");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_post)) {
     $sql_tag = mysql_query("SELECT tag.name,post.id FROM assign LEFT JOIN tag ON assign.tag_id=tag.id WHERE assign.post_id='".$row['id']."'");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.name,
    a.id
FROM
    (
        SELECT id
        FROM post
        ORDER BY time DESC
        LIMIT 5
    ) a
LEFT JOIN
    assign b ON a.id = b.post_id
LEFT JOIN
    tag c ON b.tag_id = c.id
```